# split string at index

Tags: java

How would I split a string at a particular index? e.g split string at index 10, making the string now equal to everything up to index 10 and then dumping the remainder.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What about `substring(0,10)` or `substring(0,11)` depending on whether index 10 should inclusive or not? You'd have to check for `length() >= index` though.

An alternative would be `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substring("your string", 0, 10);`

Answer (score 32):

```
String s ="123456789abcdefgh";
String sub = s.substring(0, 10);
String remainder = s.substring(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String newString = oldString.substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

this works too

```
String myString = "a long sentence that repeats itself = 1 and = 2 and = 3 again"
String removeFromThisPart = " and"

myString = myString .substring(0, myString .lastIndexOf( removeFromThisPart ));

System.out.println(myString);
```

the result should be

**a long sentence that repeats itself = 1 and = 2**

Comment: I think OP asked for an index, not the last index of known letter or word

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:`s = s.substring(0,10);`