# Java string separate number sequence

Tags: java, string, split, numbers

I get a number generated as a string that always has the same length, for example:

```
0107612733631449211907028445
```

Now I wan't to get two separate strings with the last 10 digits:

```
010761273363144921**1907028445**
```

And another string with these digits

```
0107612733**63144**9211907028445
```

The positions of these needed numbers are always the same, the numbers at the beginning are not important for me and can be omitted.

How can I get these two strings?

Comment: Search for the substring() Method. That might be useful for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split string at index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618975/split-string-at-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java docs .substring method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

```
String number = "0107612733631449211907028445";
String last10 = number.substring(number.length()-10);
```

for middle numbers use `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`